# sed replace * in url with text in json file

Tags: json, bash, unix, sed

I'm looking to change the value of a key in a json file

Example:

```
"House":"sample.house.city"
```

Need to change the word "sample" to something else.

I can do this with:

```
sed -i 's|sample.house.city|town-home.house.city|g' file.json
```

but there is no guarantee that "sample" is going to be the same every time.

I've tried:

```
sed -i 's|*.house.city|town-home.house.city|g' file.json
```

but it doesn't change.

Also tried:

```
sed -i 's|"*.house.city"|"town-home.house.city"|g' file.json
```

but that ends up like:

```
"sample"town-home.house.city"
```

Any recommendations on how to do this correctly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To match any word, you can use `[[:alnum:]_]*` (POSIX BRE) / `[[:alnum:]_]+` (POSIX ERE):

```sh
sed -i 's|[[:alnum:]_]*\.house\.city|townhome.house.city|g' file.json
```

See the [online demo](https://ideone.com/Iwbwem):

```sh
#!/bin/bash
s='"House":"sample.house.city"'
sed 's|[[:alnum:]_]*\.house\.city|townhome.house.city|g' <<< "$s"
```

Output:

```
"House":"townhome.house.city"
```

Note you also need to escape dots that are used to match literal dots.

Comment: Ran as is and it works but I left out a "-" in "townhome"
When running your code in reverse, changing "town-home" to "sample", I get "town-sample"

Recommendations?

Comment: @AlexanderGates Add the chars you consider can appear in the "word". E.g. `'s|[[:alnum:]_-]*\.house\.city|townhome.house.city|g'`

Answer (score 1):

> ##### Explanation
>
> - 1st Capturing Group (\w+)
>
>   - \w matches any word character (equivalent to [a-zA-Z0-9_])
>   - + matches the previous token between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
> - 2nd Capturing Group (.house.city)
>
>   - \. matches the character .
>   - house matches the characters house literally (case sensitive)
>   - \. matches the character .
>   - city matches the characters city literally (case sensitive)
> - Global pattern flags
>
>   - g modifier: global. All matches (don't return after first match)
> - \2 replace with the 2nd Captured Group (.house.city)

---

```
$ sed -E 's/(\w+)(\.house\.city)/town-home\2/g' <<< '"House":"sample.house.city"'

"House":"town-home.house.city"

$ sed -iE 's/(\w+)(\.house\.city)/town-home\2/g' file.json
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.